# MySQL load data infile from CSV (fields optionally enclosed by quotes, numbers have comma thousand separators)

Tags: mysql, csv

Sorry for the wordy title. I'm running the following query:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'file.csv' INTO TABLE tablename 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY ',\r\n'
```

I have a CSV with data in the following format:

```
1111, 2222, "32", "1,234.304", 1023.53,
```

All lines are terminated with an extra comma.

When attempting to load, I get an error when trying to put the "1,234.304" type field into a NUMERIC(12,4) column. I end up with 1.0000 and a warning that the data was truncated. I had expected 1234.304.

Edit: It seems that doing a regular insert for a value which has comma thousand-separators upsets MySQL. Is there a way to modify the load command for the desired behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Break the problem down into two steps:

1. Get the data into the database
2. Get the data into the table/format you want it in

If you get all the data into a table with `VARCHAR` fields, you can easily manipulate it and explicitly convert the values into the types you want them in, rather than relying on whatever implicit conversion you get with `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE`.